# If a function is twice differentiable, how would I prove that it is single differentiable

Tags: real-analysis

I feel as though it is too obvious to even prove. But I am having trouble formally proving it. My logic is that since $f''(x)$ exists then that means that
$$
\lim_{x\to a}\frac{f'(x)-f'(a)}{x-a}
$$
must also exist. Therefore, $f'(x)$ must exist in the given interval. I don't know if that is sufficient as a proof.

Comment: I also dont know if this website supports latex

Comment: Welcome! How do you define the second derivative without already using the first derivative?

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematics StackExchange!  For LaTeX, this site supports MathJax; see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference/.  As for your question, your reasoning is correct; the definition of $ f ' ' ( a ) $ doesn't make sense unless $ f ' ( a ) $ exists (and also $ f ' ( x ) $ for $ x $ sufficiently close to $ a $). Therefore $ f ' ( a ) $ must exist if $ f ' ' ( a ) $ exists; in other words, $ f $ must be differentiable at $ a $ if $ f $ is twice differentiable at $ a $.

Comment: MSE supports [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) which implements all the $\LaTeX$ commands you are likely to need. As for the maths: look at the definitions or just think: if you can pass two hurdles, can you pass one hurdle?

Comment: Nothing is too obvious to prove. Except things that come from definition, just like this question

Comment: A related question.  To what extent can $$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x-h)-2f(x)+f(x+h)}{h^2}$$exist if $f$ is not differentiable?

Comment: @GEdgar For example, it exists at $x=0$ if $f$ is an odd function.

Comment: Downvoted, because the (working) definition of twice-differentiable is not given by OP.